# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.pages.LandingPage_jsp

Tags: spring, tomcat, servlets

I'm getting two very odd errors when opening a project. If I open the landing page and keep refreshing it, the error messages alternate between the two below.

Either I get this:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /WEB-INF/pages/LandingPage.jsp (line: 2, column: 0) The absolute uri: http://www.springframework.org/security/tags cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application
```

Or this:

```
HTTP Status 500 - java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.pages.LandingPage_jsp
```

What on earth is happening?

Answer (score 4):

Because:

**Cause 1**: Parsing JSP file error. For example:
Error JSP page (due syntax error or missing dependencies):

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@page session="false" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hello world!</h1>
<p>The time on server is ${serverTime}.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Make it correct:

```
<%@page session="false" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hello world!</h1>
<p>The time on server is ${serverTime}.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

**Cause 2**: missing dependencies. Fix it by add these dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

You must set `scope` like the above.

Comment: In my problem it was 1st cause. I had unescaped " characters in jsp. Helped escaping \"

Comment: See tomcat localhost log file for checking the 1st case, not catalina! I found out this after several hours trying many things :( Hope this helps others :)

Comment: Neither of the dependencies seems to include the `forEach` tag

Answer (score 3):

In my case, AOP was reporting that I could speed up tomcat and webapp start time by adding jars to the catalina.properties section "tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToSkip", including jstl-1.2.jar.

Don't listen to this advice; only sadness will come of it.

Answer (score 1):

I had this error:
`HTTP Status 500 - java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.index_jsp`

In index.jsp i have some line:
`<%@include file="header.jsp"%>`
But clean name of file was Header.jsp. Look at your LandingPage.jsp (line: 2, column: 0) closely. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same issue once. It was resolved by changing the version of tomcat plugin from 2.0 to 2.2.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

In here you have some code line that can't be complied.
Look your code carefully.
I also put unnecessary code in my jsp page like

```
<spring:url value="/page.html">
```

Good luck!!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when deployed into remote server.But my project was working fine in local server.

After a lot of work around ,my issue was with script file used for tomcat folder.
Am sharing this if incase anyone needs in future with same kind of issue

```
#!/bin/bash
# description: Tomcat Start Stop Restart
# processname: tomcat
# chkconfig: 234 20 80
JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk1.8.0_60
export JAVA_HOME
PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
export PATH
export TOMCAT_HOME=/usr/tomcat7
export JEE_JAR=$JAVA_HOME
export JRE_HOME=$JAVA_HOME
export CLASSPATH=.:$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib:$JAVA_HOME/lib:$JAVA_HOME/lib/tools.jar
CATALINA_HOME=/usr/tomcat7

case $1 in
start)
sh $CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh
;;
stop)
sh $CATALINA_HOME/bin/shutdown.sh
;;
restart)
sh $CATALINA_HOME/bin/shutdown.sh
sh $CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh
;;
esac
exit 0
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case a simple application rebuild-redeploy helped me to solve the similar exception. It seems like some resources (jsp ?) were missing in the initial build.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was caused by tomcat putting compiled jsps into /tmp which then got cleared. This is reported issue: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/5009

Answer (score 0):

This might also be caused by following hints that effectively disable JSP support in Tomcat 8+ to improve (startup) performance.

Do *not* include `JasperInitializer` in the context’s `containerSciFilter` property (in `conf/context.xml`).

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was wrong filepaths to `jsp:include` pages, changed to this:

```
<%@ include file = "/WEB-INF/views/shared/header.jsp" %>
```

For this project structure (inside a deployed war's folder in /webapps):

```
webapps
  mywar
    META-INF
    resources
      css
      img
    WEB-INF
      classes
      lib
      views
        login.jsp/etc
      index.jsp
```