# When I call pageContext.request.contextPath in .jsp file throw java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.JSP.login_jsp

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat, web-applications

dev evn: IDEA
Technology involves：tomcat + spring mvc + shiro

When I call pageContext.request.contextPath in .jsp file throw  java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.JSP.login_jsp

What is the caused?

**Maven Dependency:**

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

full error:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.JSP.login_jsp
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:197)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:413)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:386)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:330)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:168)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1286)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1041)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:984)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:61)
    org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.executeChain(AdviceFilter.java:108)
    org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.doFilterInternal(AdviceFilter.java:137)
    org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
    org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:66)
    org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.executeChain(AbstractShiroFilter.java:449)
    org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1.call(AbstractShiroFilter.java:365)
    org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90)
    org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.call(SubjectCallable.java:83)
    org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.execute(DelegatingSubject.java:383)
    org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:362)
    org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:347)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:263)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
```

JSP FILE,as follows:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Home</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        Welcome! <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/Login">Login</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

This question has puzzled me all day.

Who can help me? Thank,very, very much!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25360722/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-apache-jsp-web-002dinf-pages-landingpage-j might help

Comment: share with us your JSP page so we can figure out the cause