# why pageContext.request.contextPath is treated as a string and not as classpath?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jsp, el

as i use my

```
<a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/rest/hello">Hello</a>
```

my url becomes

```
http://localhost:8080/spring-rest-demo/$%7BpageContext.request.contextPath%7D/rest/hello
```

why is this happening

i have javax.servlet-api and javax.servlet.jsp-api dependency in my pom file as well

and it is a jsp file not html

Answer (score 0):

Expressions like ${pageContext.request.contextPath} cannot be used in a plain HTML file, they must be used inside a JSP file. I suggest you start by reading a few tutorials about Java servlets and JSP.

You can simply ignore it.

If you really want to redirect it to another page. So, you need to add `JSTL Dependency` to use the expression language.

I recommend you to use `Thymeleaf` which is easy to use and you can easily play with the controller's

Comment: it is a jsp file not plain html file

Comment: can u share your pom file and error logs might your dependency is too old

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25360722/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-apache-jsp-web-002dinf-pages-landingpage-j   

It helps you

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, `classpath` is a completely different thing. What you wanted to mean is ***Context Path***.

It seems that you don't have [Expression Language (EL)](https://javaee.github.io/tutorial/jsf-el.html) in your classpath. Add this to your dependencies:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

This should fix the issue with resolving `${pageContext.request.contextPath}`.

**Suggestion**

Use [`url`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/url.html) tag from `JSTL`. Or, [`url`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/spring-tld.html#spring.tld.url) tag from Spring Framework.